# Conditional (Ternary) Operator Code Style

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

> `int foo = bar > baz ? bar : baz;`
>
> `int foo = someBoolean ? bar : baz;`
>
> ---
>
> `int foo = (bar > baz) ? bar : baz;`
>
> `int foo = (someBoolean) ? bar : baz;`
>
> ---
>
> `int foo = (bar > baz) ? bar : baz;`
>
> `int foo = someBoolean ? bar : baz;`

I can't decide which of these three I should use. I can:

1. Use no parentheses and risk bad readability in examples such as:

   `min[0] = min[0] > pos.x ? pos.x : 0;`
2. Always use parentheses, but risk
   somewhat ugly code in short expressions:

   `setValue(val + scrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * ((scrollsUp) ? -1 : 1));`
3. Stay somewhere in between and use parentheses when there are spaces
   in the condition, but not if the condition is just a boolean
   variable:

   `min[0] = (min[0] > pos.x) ? pos.x : 0;`

   `setValue(val + scrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * (scrollsUp ? -1 : 1));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracles [`Code Conventions`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#331) states the following

```
return (condition ? x : y);
```

.. and further

```
if (a == b && c == d)     // AVOID!
if ((a == b) && (c == d)) // RIGHT
```

...which is freely translated to

```
return (someBoolean ? x : y);
return ((x > y) ? x : y);
```

.. although on a personal note I wouldn't mind relaxing a parenthesis or two. 
In the end it's still a subjective matter. If you feel adding/removing a parenthesis offers better readability, then by all means feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Clarity rules over anything in my case, so I'd go with:

```
int foo = (bar > baz) ? bar : baz;
int foo = (someBoolean) ? bar : baz;
```

Comment: Thanks for being helpful and answering questions. The question you've answered has been closed because this is the sort of thing that results in lengthy debates rather than a solution to a problem someone has. I'd like to advise that in the future it's worth avoiding these questions that are about opinions or where there's controversy because they're likely to get closed and deleted (so also any reputation you earned answering them would then disappear).

Answer (score 0):

i personally would prefer case 2:

```
     int foo = (bar > baz) ? bar : baz;

    int foo = (someBoolean) ? bar : baz;
```

as the conditions are inside brackets.

This piece of code

```
 int foo = bar > baz ? bar : baz;
```

would effect readability but would compile perfectly. buti think putting the test condition in the brackets would be better for readability.
however i would say it mostly depends on the persons style of coding. nonethless all the threecase would work fine :)